# Play Multiple animation in sequence

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to execute ball blasting effect to play sequentially. One after another.

**What I have done yet:**

For ball blasting effect i had used

```
UIButton *ballButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:10];

ballButton.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                        nil];
ballButton.imageView.animationDuration = 1;
ballButton.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

and this line on code is attached to multiple buttons in a cell of a collection view.
I call these `ballbutton.imageview` start the animation like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        NSIndexPath *path2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [ballContainer cellForItemAtIndexPath:path2];
        UIButton *ballObject = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:10];
        [ballObject.imageView startAnimating];
    } completion:^(BOOL b){
          NSLog(@" here i call next animation of ball blast to execute ");
}];
```

I nested 3 animations buttons like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way i solved my issue.
initially i started animation by calling this

```
        [self startAnim:index];
```

than implemented this StartAnim like this and problem solved.

```
-(void)StartAnim :(int)x{

    NSIndexPath *path2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:0];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [ballContainer cellForItemAtIndexPath:path2];
    UIButton *ballObject = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:10];
    [ballObject setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ballObject.imageView.image = nil;
    [ballObject.imageView startAnimating];

    double delayInSeconds = 0.15;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        if(x-6>=0){
            [self StartAnim :(x-6)];
        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why don't you create one big animation for all other three? The thing with the `UIView animateWithDuration:` is that it performs the animation block in the period of time you gave to it, i.e. setting the frame from (200,200) to (0,0) will move it proportionally in the time of a second, in your case. But `UIImageView`'s properties regarding animations are made in such way that the animation is already done for you.

Personally, I would suggest using a timer, like this:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ballObject.imageView.animationDuration
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(performNextAnimation:) 
                                                userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[ballObject.imageView startAnimating];
```

And in the `performNextAnimation` method:

```
- (void) performNextAnimation{
[timer invalidate]; // you have to access the timer you've scheduled with the animation
timer = nil;
/* code for starting the next animation */
}
```